# Build a simple, high performance Tree Data Structure in c#

Tags: c#, tree

I need to create a product catalog, in tree type.

every tree node presents by a ID(string), the functions on the tree data only 2:

1. `getChild(string ID)`, give a ID, get children (no need include childrens'
   children), if ID is null, get all root nodes
2. `getParent(string ID)`, return     parent ID if have, or null if is root

Since once the tree decided, will not change, so I think put all code in static will be best.
So I start to try use Dictionary

```
"id": {parent:ID, child:[id2, id3, id4....]}
```

Since theres about 1000+ catalog, I found I quickly mess myself up, lots of mistake in the static data, and make final result on usable. Also, now I only wrote dozens and the code is looking like mess.

Please advice a way create this simple catalog tree with high performance. Thanks

Comment: What is your original data source?  XML? Entities? Json?

Comment: original data is on another total different language, so I need to write this in c#, plain hard coded c# code is fine for me since once done, the structure will not change.

Comment: "since once done, the structure will not change".... doubt that :D

Comment: @Jeroen, maybe need change, then I just put extra code, recompile, redeployment. It will not happen everyday.

Comment: A robust tree structure withstands the test of time (and feature requests).

Comment: “I found I quickly mess myself up, lots of mistake in the static data” Why do you think any other approach would contain less mistakes?

Comment: @svick, I was manually hard code the tree structure, so may have the situation that parent sait it has 5 children, but not all 5 children said they have the parent :( But for solution from Yorye Nathan, tree is generated

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Just make a class out of it.

**UPDATED:**

```
class TreeNode : IEnumerable<TreeNode>
{
    private readonly Dictionary<string, TreeNode> _children =
                                        new Dictionary<string, TreeNode>();

    public readonly string ID;
    public TreeNode Parent { get; private set; }

    public TreeNode(string id)
    {
        this.ID = id;
    }

    public TreeNode GetChild(string id)
    {
        return this._children[id];
    }

    public void Add(TreeNode item)
    {
        if (item.Parent != null)
        {
            item.Parent._children.Remove(item.ID);
        }

        item.Parent = this;
        this._children.Add(item.ID, item);
    }

    public IEnumerator<TreeNode> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return this._children.Values.GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return this.GetEnumerator();
    }

    public int Count
    {
        get { return this._children.Count; }
    }
}
```

Usage will be fairly simple to statically define:

```
var tree = new TreeNode("Root")
               {
                   new TreeNode("Category 1")
                       {
                           new TreeNode("Item 1"),
                           new TreeNode("Item 2"),
                           new TreeNode("Item 3"),
                       },
                   new TreeNode("Category 2")
                       {
                           new TreeNode("Item 1"),
                           new TreeNode("Item 2"),
                           new TreeNode("Item 3"),
                           new TreeNode("Item 4"),
                       }
               };
```

**Edit**

Some more functionality for even easier creation...

```
public static TreeNode BuildTree(string tree)
{
    var lines = tree.Split(new[] { Environment.NewLine },
                           StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

    var result = new TreeNode("TreeRoot");
    var list = new List<TreeNode> { result };

    foreach (var line in lines)
    {
        var trimmedLine = line.Trim();
        var indent = line.Length - trimmedLine.Length;

        var child = new TreeNode(trimmedLine);
        list[indent].Add(child);

        if (indent + 1 < list.Count)
        {
            list[indent + 1] = child;
        }
        else
        {
            list.Add(child);
        }
    }

    return result;
}

public static string BuildString(TreeNode tree)
{
    var sb = new StringBuilder();

    BuildString(sb, tree, 0);

    return sb.ToString();
}

private static void BuildString(StringBuilder sb, TreeNode node, int depth)
{
    sb.AppendLine(node.ID.PadLeft(node.ID.Length + depth));

    foreach (var child in node)
    {
        BuildString(sb, child, depth + 1);
    }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
var tree = TreeNode.BuildTree(@"
Cat1
 Sub1
  Item1
  Item2
  Item3
 Sub2
  Item1
  Item2
Cat2
 Sub1
 Sub2
  Item1
  Item2
 Sub3
  Item1
Cat3
Cat4");
```

Comment: @EricYin See updates and edits, and also note that you can make the Add method private if you wish, by making the static TreeNode ctor build the static tree, or you could "signal" the tree to become read-only so the Add method will become obsolete or throw a readonly exception.

Comment: @YoryeNathan: +1 Nice work. You might consider an `AttachTo(TreeNode parent)` method for setting the parent, and the parent's children accordingly. Maybe a `Detach()` method also.

Comment: @YoryeNathan, very nice work. Ask an off topic question: the tree will be built at runtime at once, right? Since it's do not need to change, can I build the tree at or before compile? I count I total have 3600+ catalog, will see how long need to build the tree. I hope it's quick, then I do not need to worry about the build time.

Comment: @YoryeNathan the build on 3600+ lines almost instant. I am very happy with your solution, thanks.

Comment: @ja72 Thank you. Regarding the suggestion: adding a node to a parent will automatically remove it from the previous parent and re-set the parent property. The only thing you cant do is detach, but since there is one static tree which is built in a straightforward fashion, it isnt much needed.

Comment: @EricYin I cant think pf any way other then a messed up memory hogging dictionary to do that. happy to hear this works for you smoothly :)

Comment: @YoryeNathan The function is fast but slightly differ of want I want. E.g `GetChild("Cat2")` should return a `List<string> {"Sub1", "Sub2", "Sub3" }` but currently return `"Cat2", "Sub1", "Sub2", "Sub3", "Item1"...` I guess I forget to mention all IDs are unique in whole tree. I may use recursion to get all childrens but for `GetChild()` function, only current child(s) is enough. Btw, I also cannot get rootNode, which is the node has no parents, I tried `GetChild("TreeRoot")`, not working. I am study the logic behind your code now, hope I can roll something my own. If you like to help, please.

Comment: The getChild method is an instance mehod. It returns the child of the tree node that has the specified name. To get all childs of Cat2, for example, you should the instance of Cat2 as an IEnumerator. Regarding the root - you should keep a static reference to the root, as ot is your entry point for all other nodes. To find a node with a specific id, not necesseraly a direct child of a node, you should use a static recursion based method using the root as the search start, or also keep a static dictionary to contain ALL nodes.

Comment: Could somebody show an example of how to make the first version above use generics instead of being typed to string only?

Comment: @BadmintonCat For real purposes I would suggest making the `ID` an `int` and add a `T` field to hold the actual node data.

Comment: @YoryeNathan Ok but how/where do you add the T in this case? because `class TreeNode<T> : IEnumerable<TreeNode>` doesn't work.

Comment: Nevermind! I found the solution here: https://code.google.com/p/yet-another-tree-structure/wiki/CSharpTree

Comment: What is the best method to search for nodes by id on a tree created with this class?

Comment: @Nate For such task I would have each node get a reference to the Root upon creation, so it can inform the Root when nodes are added. The Root should have a "global id" dictionary for all elements in the tree. That also means the "id" of a node isn't "Item2" but rather "Cat2>Sub3>Item2" (in case you're actually using "titles" as ids.. Otherwise simply generate unique integers). Then you can access any node by id in `O(1)`

Comment: @SimpleVar could you give me a quick example of that? Im not exactly sure what you mean

Comment: @Nate without modifying the current code, you'd do something like `find(x,id) { x._children.ContainsKey(id) ? x._children[id] : x._children.values.FirstOrDefault(child => find(child, id)) }

Comment: @SimpleVar This makes sense to me, but what variable is `x` representing in the `find()` call?

Comment: `x` represents the current node in which we're searching. Here is the method you would add, without changing anything else: http://pastebin.com/AJREYjrU *This is not the optimal solution* - Effectively the search performs at `O(n)` even though it uses dictionaries. With a single global dictionary, you can find any element in the tree at `O(1)` performance.

Comment: I definitely need a tree. I just  need to search a tree for an ID and return the path of the tree to get to that node

Comment: @Nate Yeah, its still a tree. But on top of the tree, there is also a dictionary of all elements in the tree, by their id's (globally unique). To get the path from the found node, simply backtrack it's `.Parent` until you reach the root. Ultimately, having a per-node dictionary for only direct children might prove to be pointless, depending on needs. IMO *only global dictionary* is the way to go.

Comment: With Net Core I was required to cast the IEnumerator IEnumerable return to a IEnumerator type.

Answer (score 15):

I created a [Node class](https://www.siepman.nl/blog/a-generic-tree-of-nodes-the-easy-way) that could be helpfull. It is fast and has some extra properties, like:

- Ancestors
- Descendants
- Siblings
- Level of the node
- Parent
- Root
- Etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can write a simple binary tree , I wrote some Pseudo code beloew:

```
class TreeNode {
    TreeNode Right;
    TreeNode Left;
    int id;
    //...
}

class BinTree {

    void Insert(TreeNode node)
    {
        while(true) {   
            if(node.id > target.id) {
                if(target.Right != null) {
                    target = target.Right;
                    continue;
                }
                else {
                    target.Right = node;
                    break;
                }
            }

            else if(node.id < target.id) {
                if(target.Left != null) {
                    target = target.Left;
                    continue;
                }
                else {
                    target.Left = node;
                    break;
                }   
            }

            else {
                throw new ArgumentException("Duplicated id");
            }
        }
    }


    TreeNode Search(int id)
    {
        TreeNode target = root;

        while(target != null) {
            if(id > target.id) {
                target = target.Right;
            }
            else if(id < target.id) {
                target = target.Left;
            }
            else {
                return target;
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

}
```

But if your data count is very large, maybe AVL tree is more efficient

Comment: -1 Doesn't answer his need at all. He wants a tree for a product catalog. Binary tree is far from what he needs, and even after that, he doesn't need it balanced or sorted in any matter, as the catalog has a logical structure to maintain.

Comment: +1: Not what I was thinking of, but the OP didn't give a preference to the type of tree structure.

Comment: @YoryeNathan: I disagree. The OP didn't give a preference except for 2 requirements: **simple**, **performance**. This answer provides both. Simplicity may be lost on those that don't understand what the tree is doing, but it is certainly more efficient than the linear (or unbalanced) tree.

Comment: @IAbstract One thing is to read what the person is asking for, and another thing is understanding what he needs. He needs to represent a catalog, which has no binary-tree properties/constraints whatsoever.

Comment: @YoryeNathan: I understood what the OP was asking and my initial thought was the same sort of structure you presented. This answer has merit and could be implemented to serve the OP's needs. If performance is going to be an issue, then this is the better of the two options. If simplicity is preferred, then the standard unbalanced tree is the better of the two options.

Comment: @IAbstract How is this better at performance if a catalog by definition is unbalanced and unsorted?

Comment: @YoryelNathan: It comes down to separating concerns: a view model to customize the data structure. In llj098 proposal, he presents a data structure that is both simple and fast. The view model can customize the source in an unbalanced tree - so I don't see the problem. Your solution combines both concerns - but you have forced the data structure to take on the requirements of the view model. I'm not saying your answer is wrong, and for this particular instance, it is the best and most correct. My initial argument was simply that this answer *has merit*. :)

Comment: @IAbstract I agree it can provide a starting point and accept your argument. -1 will be removed once enabled.