# ASP.NET Is there a simple way to store data in a tree other than treeview?

Tags: asp.net

So I have a menu system that uses a tree to hold its values, but its currently in a treeview and I don't want to display the tree so the "view" part is unnecessary. I'm sure this is an inefficient way to organize a tree, so I was wondering if theirs a tree data structure in c# or if I'd have to make a simple one from scratch or even if the treeview saps enough effiiency from a web app to bother with?

thanks

Comment: What do you mean by the "view" part is not necessary?

Comment: @RayCheng - the OP wants to store data in a tree structure, but not display it to the user.

Comment: Using a user control to store data transcends the concept of overkill. You did something big there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no built-in tree data structure in C#, but you can create your own as described in the answer to this previous question [Build a simple, high performance Tree Data Structure in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9860207/build-a-simple-high-performance-tree-data-structure-in-c-sharp).