# Scanning , Parsing

Tags: c#, compiler-construction

I'm writing simple compiler without using grammar Generators. [Here](http://s13.postimg.org/jxg87g23b/project.png)
. I wrote the scanning code that read file.txt ,and classify it to Identifier or Revers words , Number , Variable ..etc.
I got the result that I want but Is it possible to complete with this code I mean applying syntax Analysis ? and parsing ? . Because I I tried make it with java and I coded it with wrong way . I want see if I do it right ,specially i'm not good in C# codding .

Arrays :

```
 string[] Rw = new string[8];
        Rw[0] = "for";
        Rw[1] = "while";
        Rw[2] = "end";
        Rw[3] = "contiune";
        Rw[4] = "if";
        Rw[5] = "break";
        Rw[6] = "do";
        Rw[7] = "return";
        string[] id = new string[6];
        id[0] = "int";
        id[1] = "float";
        id[2] = "string";
        id[3] = "double";
        id[4] = "bool";
        id[5] = "char";
        string[] op = new string[6];
        op[0] = "+";
        op[1] = "-";
        op[2] = "/";
        op[3] = "*";
        op[4] = "%";
        string[] Num = new string[10];
        Num[0] = "0";
        Num[1] = "1";
        Num[2] = "2";
        Num[3] = "3";
        Num[4] = "4";
        Num[5] = "5";
        Num[6] = "6";
        Num[7] = "7";
        Num[8] = "8";
        Num[9] = "9";

        string[] var = new string[17];
     var[0] = "a";
     var[1] = "b";
     var[2] = "A";
     var[3] = "B";
     var[4] = "C";
     var[5] = "d";
     var[6] = "D";
     var[7] = "X";
     var[8] = "x";
     var[9] = "Y";
     var[10] = "y";
     var[11] = "z";
     var[12] = "Z";
     var[13] = "v";
     var[14] = "V";
     var[15] = "f";
     var[16] = "F";
```

Reading and Split :

```
        char[] delimiterChars = { ' ', ',', '.', ':', '\t' };
        using (System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(@"C:\Users\caza\Desktop\1.txt"))
    {
        while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
        {


            string[] token = line.Split(delimiterChars);


            foreach (string s in token)
            {
             // Console.WriteLine(s);
                foreach (string z in Rw)
                {
                    if (s == z)
                    {

                        Console.WriteLine(s + " is a Reserved Word ");

                    }

                }
                foreach (string y in id)
                {
                    if (s == y)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(s + " is a identifier ");

                    }
                }
                    foreach (string o in op)
                    {
                        if (s == o)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(s + " is a Operation ");
                        }
                    }

                    foreach (string n in Num)
                    {
                        if (s == n)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(s + " is  a Number ");
                        }
                    }
                    foreach (string v in var)
                    {
                        if (s == v)
                        {



                            Console.WriteLine(s + " is a Variable");
                        }
                    }
            }


            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit.");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure what the question is.

Comment: I split the tokens and compare it Okay . now is possible to apply Syntax analysis .  for example : I say identifier should be followed by Variable and Variable should be followed by ; ... , if wrong I return error .

Comment: Definitely if you want to parse text and check if it applies all rules and there is no syntax error!You should parse token in a data structure like a tree.

Comment: @saeed is it possible I make parse tree in C# by codding not a Grammar ?

Comment: I know parse tree come from grammar but I draw parents and child's tree . I dunno if it is possible with these strings arrays .

Comment: I think I found it , I will make the tree by XML file and read it as it's my rules .  I hope it will work with this code . Thank you

Comment: [Tree](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9860207/build-a-simple-high-performance-tree-data-structure-in-c-sharp)[Tree][1]

Comment: @Amador Yes it's possible.