# EF6 - How is the most efficient way to get all children in an ICollection?

Tags: entity-framework-6, icollection

In EF6, how is the most efficient way to get all children of a DbSet object, where the DbSet object can have children and the children are in an `ICollection`?

Here is my class:

```
public class Simple
{
    [Key]
    public int id { get; set; }
    public int? simpleId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("simpleId")]
    public virtual Simple simple { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Simple> simpleObjects { get; set; }
}
```

Here is some code that I have:

```
public IQueryable<Simple> GetAll(params Expression<Func<Simple, object>>[] includeExpressions)
{
    IQueryable<Simple> set = db.Simple;

    foreach (var includeExpression in includeExpressions)
    {
        set = set.Include(includeExpression);
    }
    return set;
}
```

I am calling the function with the following code:

```
IQueryable<Simple> getAll = GetAll(o=> o.simpleObjects);
```

This is returning all of the `Simple` objects in the DbSet.

How can I get all the children of a specific `Simple` object, where I have the `Simple` object, rather than all of the `Simple` objects in the whole DbSet?

Comment: Try the answer of this question [sorting Self-Referencing Relationship] [sorting Self-Referencing Relationship]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35814586/sorting-self-referencing-relationship/35816143#35816143

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure this is what you want but it may help.

```
public IQueryable<TEntity> GetItems(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate, params Expression<Func<TEntity, object>>[] includeProperties)
{
    var query = predicate == null 
                    ? dbContext.EntitySet<TEntity>() 
                    : dbContext.EntitySet<TEntity>().Where(predicate);

    if (includeProperties != null)
        query = ApplyIncludesOnQuery(query, includeProperties);

    return query;
}

public IQueryable<TEntity> ApplyIncludesOnQuery(IQueryable<TEntity> query, params Expression<Func<TEntity, object>>[] includeProperties)
{
    //Return Applied Includes query
    return (includeProperties.Aggregate(query, (currentEntity, navigation) => currentEntity.Include(navigation)));
}
```

Get All with navigation

```
var allItesm = GetItems<Simple>(null, s => s.simpleObjects)
```

Get Specific with navigation

```
var item = GetItems<Simple>(s => s.Id == someId, s => s.simpleObjects)
```

Get Specific without navigation

```
var item = GetItems<Simple>(s => s.Id == someId)
```

Comment: Can you please explain what the EntitySet() variable is?

Comment: `EntitySet()` is `DbContext.EntitySet`.