# Making a tree stucture out of list of strings in c# (winForms)

Tags: c#, algorithm, winforms, treeview, nodes

I am struggling with some logic for making tree structure out of string that I need to pull from database and add to `TreeView` control.
For the sake of explanation, i have created a small example in `winforms`
Let's say I have some list of strings

```
 private List<string> strings;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            strings = new List<string>
            {
                "Root1.Parrent1",
                "Root1.Parrent2",
                "Root1.Parrent3.Child1", 
                "Root1.Parrent4.Child2",             
                "Root2.newParrent1.newChild1",
                "Root2.newParrent1.newChild2",
                "Root2.NewParrent2"
            };
        }
```

So I want to distinct every repeated element and make a hierarchy that looks like this, note that I have repeated roots as well as parrents (newparrent1)

```
 main root {
 root1(                  root2(
    parrent1               newParrent1(
    parrent2                       --newChild1
    parrent3(--child1)             --newChild2)
    parrent4(--child2)     newParrent2)

       }
```

So far my logic is cartoon, I don't even know where to begin, I don't know how menu sub nodes will one node have, done some [research](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9860207/build-a-simple-high-performance-tree-data-structure-in-c-sharp), but couldn't get the answer.
I have created example only for the first item of `strings` list, just to see how my logic would go.

```
 string[] splitsArray = strings[0].Split('.');

    TreeNode node = new TreeNode();
    node.Text = splitsArray[0];         
    //creating sub node
    TreeNode subNode = new TreeNode();
    subNode.Text = splitsArray[1];
    //adding
    node.Nodes.Add(subNode);
    treeView1.Nodes[0].Nodes.Add(node);
```

Can't even see how could I put this logic into a loop.
Any suggestion is helpful, even pseudo code. thank you for your time.

Comment: hash table of nodes. if you assume the tree is valid then you can do that in O(n) run time

Comment: give me some time I'll write a code that could work, then I'll explain it but above all I'll explain how I got there so the next time you'll be more at ease

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Your code goes here
            Console.WriteLine("Hello, world!");
            List<string> strings;
            strings = new List<string>()
            {
                "Root1.Parrent1",
                "Root1.Parrent2",
                "Root1.Parrent3.Child1",
                "Root1.Parrent4.Child2",
                "Root2.newParrent1.newChild1",
                "Root2.newParrent1.newChild2",
                "Root2.NewParrent2"
            };
            eat e = new eat(strings);
            Console.WriteLine(e.root.ToJson());
            Console.WriteLine("Press enter to close...");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
    public class eat
    {
        public node root;
        public eat(List<string> l)
        {
            root = new node("root");
            foreach(string s in l)
            {
                addRow(s);
            }

        }
        public void addRow(string s)
        {
            List<string> l = s.Split('.').ToList<String>();
            node state = root;
            foreach(string ss in l)
            {
                addSoon(state, ss);
                state = getSoon(state, ss);
            }
        }
        private void addSoon(node n, string s)
        {
            bool f = false;
            foreach(node ns in n.soon)
            {
                if (ns.name == s) { f = !f; }
            }
            if (!f) { n.soon.Add(new node(s)); }

        }
        private node getSoon(node n,string s)
        {
            foreach (node ns in n.soon)
            {
                if (ns.name == s) { return ns; }
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
    public class node
    {
        public node(string n)
        {
            name = n;
            soon = new List<node>();
        }
        public string name;
        public List<node> soon;

        public string ToJson()
        {
            String s = "";
            s = s + "{\"name\":\"" + name + "\",\"soon\":[";
            bool f = true;
            foreach(node n in soon)
            {
                if (f) { f = !f; } else { s = s + ","; }
                s = s + n.ToJson();
            }
            s = s + "]}";
            return s;
        }
    }
```

this is a solution without the use of dictionaries
we have an eater that has the task of processing and stacking node-like objects
then we have the node that deals with managing the element and the children.

he class tojson is used to verify correct operation

outpot:

```
{
  "name": "root",
  "soon": [
    {
      "name": "Root1",
      "soon": [
        {
          "name": "Parrent1",
          "soon": [

          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "Parrent2",
          "soon": [

          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "Parrent3",
          "soon": [
            {
              "name": "Child1",
              "soon": [

              ]
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "Parrent4",
          "soon": [
            {
              "name": "Child2",
              "soon": [

              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "Root2",
      "soon": [
        {
          "name": "newParrent1",
          "soon": [
            {
              "name": "newChild1",
              "soon": [

              ]
            },
            {
              "name": "newChild2",
              "soon": [

              ]
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "NewParrent2",
          "soon": [

          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

**UPDATE**

I've just added recursive method into `node` class that will return `TreeNode` obj so I can put in `TreeView`, thank you , this is very useful

```
 public TreeNode GetRoot(List<node> nodes, TreeNode parrent)
        {
            foreach (var node in nodes)                   
              parrent.Nodes.Add(GetRoot(node.children, new TreeNode(node.name)));

            return parrent;
        }
```

!!!!--- Steve's solution is more correct, using dictionaries ---!!!

Comment: works like charm, give mi some time to experiment with solution.

Comment: sure no problem

Comment: how the experiment went?

Comment: Thank you for the answer,all answers were very useful, I've used Reza answer for now because of simplification, I could easily used it on `DataTable`, later on I will make my own solution. thank you again.

Comment: thank you for this, it took me a while to understand this, this is good example because it is dynamic, it can be adjusted, I've just added recursive method in `node` class that will return `TreeNode` object, so I can put in `TreeView.`

Comment: @GianfrancescoAurecchia _"Steve's solution is more correct"_ I don't think it is. See my comment under his solution.

Answer (score 2):

Since tagged it as an algorithm question I will provide the algorithm only and leave the coding part as your exercise.

First you make a Dictionary of all the nodes with the key being the node name and value as the node object

```
Dictionary<string, Node> nodes;
```

and a parent table

```
Dictionary<string, string> childParent;
```

then you iterate thru all the strings and split the parts, for each part you check if the name exists in the `nodes` Dictionary, if not then add them in

and add the parent to the parent table. For example

```
Root2.newParrent1.newChild1
```

You will add `(newParrent1, Root2)` and `(newChild1, newParrent1)` to the `childParent` table

Now you have a dictionary of the nodes and parent, we can start making the dependency.

you go thru the `childParent` table we just created, and add the node to their corresponding parent's `Children` property

for example if you have `(newParrent1, Root2)`

you will be doing `nodes["Root2"].Children.Add(nodes["newParrent1"]);`

Oh, did we forget about the root node?

I will leave that as exercise too.

Comment: I thought about using Dictionaries as solution, just splitting part was confusing, thank you for the algorithm, I am always looking forward to exercise, do you think I can use `recursion` here?

Comment: @djordje.petrovic012 to use recursion efficiently you would need a top down structure ready. But for your case I don't think you do. as for the split part its straight forward, you can just string.split on '.' and do a for loop on the result array. first do an add on current node to the nodes table, then another add to the childParent table if i is > 0. I.E. we have a parent (hint: you could do something else here for the root exercise part)

Comment: _"First you make a Dictionary of all the nodes with the key being the node name"_ Are you sure? What happens when I have the same nodes named the same but in different parts of the tree? For example, I have a node named `MyNode` in `root/MyNode` and then `MyNode` in `root/OtherNode/MyNode`. This algorithm seems to break under these conditions: what will you do when it's time to populate the tree: to which one of those nodes are you going to add all the children that report `MyNode` as their parent?

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a way to add those strings to `TreeView` you can use following code. The answer is trying to do it with minimal code:

```
treeView1.BeginUpdate();
foreach (var s in strings)
{
    TreeNode node = null;
    foreach (var text in s.Split('.'))
    {
        var key = (node == null ? $"{text}" : $"{node.Name}.{text}");
        var nodes = (TreeNodeCollection)((dynamic)node ?? (dynamic)treeView1).Nodes;
        node = (nodes.Find(key, false)).FirstOrDefault() ?? nodes.Add(key, text);
    }
}
treeView1.EndUpdate();
```

The reason for using `dynamic` in above code, is because both `TreeView` and `TreeNode` have `Nodes` collection. You can use dynamic or you can have two different branches of code (`if(node == null){...}/else{...}`) which are quiet similar.

Just for your information `TreeNodes` collection has a `Find` method which allows you to find a node by key. The answer relies on setting key for the node when adding which allows us to find it later simply.

Comment: nice explanation and not too many lines of code, just tell me do I have to worry about performance in this case, because I will read a lot of data from Database?

Comment: Give it a try.  I guess the performance is good enough. Just keep in mind if you are adding many nodes, you should call `treeView1.BeginUpdate()` before loop and `treeView1.EndUpdate()` after loop, to prevent flickering and taking less time.

Comment: I changed the answer to add `BeginUpdate` and `EndUpdate`. Also converted `.Nodes` to `NodeCollection` to bring types back and limit the dynamic to the minimal possible part of code.

Comment: Tested on database, works like charm  and the `Find` method is very useful, thank you, if you could add pseudo to your answer just for batter understanding I would really appreciate it. from my conclusion code goes like this:  `1. split strings and loop through array, 2. add key to node (if node is null add text, else add node name) 3 and 4...`

Comment: The code is self-explanatory and it's really hard for me to describe it. I tried but the amount of the description is much more than the amount of code :)).

Comment: okay, no worries :), just i am trying to add some dynamic in this so that I don't depend from tree view, but I will think of something, for now this is great

Comment: Clever unreadable one-liners that only the writer can understand. It would be much better if it was written in 20 lines of code with explanatory variables, that would be much easier to understand, edit and extend, than these 3 lines.